# How to add the diagram code to the table name in the SQL generation in Powerdesigner?

Tags: powerdesigner

I have limited experience hacking PowerDesigner so I don't even know if what I need would be possible.

**Context:** I'm doing a Proof of Concept of HP Vertica data modeling. Since PowerDesigner does not have any xdb for Vertica I'm doing the PoC as ANSI SQL.

**Problem:** In ANSI SQL the SQL generated is neutral and compatible with Vertica, but I cannot handle DB users (read owners) so there is no information related to Schema or table owner when the SQL is generated. I would need something like

```
CREATE TABLE owner_name.table_name
```

instead of what I get now

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
```

Despite not being able to use table owners, I'm grouping them in different diagrams, so I could solve the "problem" if I could generate in the SQL code something like

```
CREATE TABLE diagram_name.table_name
```

since the outcome in the SQL code would be the same even if I'm not using strictly the DB users it would work for me perfectly. What I don't know is if this is even possible in PowerDesigner, and if so, where to tune o hack to achieve this.

Any hint?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can probably get the result you want, by creating a Computed Extended Attribute on the Table, where you will walk up to the diagram, through the Symbols collection. However, it might be better to enable to User object in your modified DBMS; for example, compare the ANSI SQL with the ORACLE DBMS...

Comment: Thank you, Pascal. I've tried your proposal of using the Oracle xdb and it works with some minor tuning and simpler than creating computed extended attributes, what could be out of my current ability.